# SQL Sum with query and Group by

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

[image]

like this and would like to count bill on tblsoinvoiceheader with sum on sub query by condition on ProductCode = Discount-1000

What kind of query should I have?

Comment: my-sql or sql-server? They're totally different systems

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.) And don't forget to specify the expected result as well.

Comment: share your table schema and expected output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have at most one `DISCOUNT` line per invoice, then you can use:

```
SELECT h.TransactionDate,
       COUNT(*) AS CountOfBill,
       SUM(h.InvoiceAmountWithTax) AS InvoiceAmountWithTax,
       SUM(CASE WHEN i.Remark = 'Discount' THEN -i.LineAmountWithTax END) AS Discount
FROM tblsoinvoiceheader h LEFT JOIN
     tblsoinvoiceitem i
     ON i.DocNo = h.DocNo AND
        i.Remark = 'Discount'
GROUP BY h.TransactionDate;
```

If you can have multiple discounts per doc, then you need to pre-aggregate.

Comment: This is my solution

Answer (score 0):

To prepare data in `tblsoinvoiceheader` we need to use such query:

```
select TransactionDate, 
       count(*) CountOfBill, 
       sum(InvoiceAmountWithTax) InvoiceAmountWithTax 
from tblsoinvoiceheader
group by TransactionDate
```

and then join it with result of below query:

```
select (-1)*LineAmountWithTax
from tblsoinvoiceitem
where ProductCode = 'Discount-1000'
```

Summing up:

```
select * from (
    select (-1)*LineAmountWithTax
    from tblsoinvoiceitem
    where ProductCode = 'Discount-1000'
-- i used cross join because you didn't specify joining condition and it looks like you want to 
-- join all recrods
) a cross join (
    select TransactionDate, 
           count(*) CountOfBill, 
           sum(InvoiceAmountWithTax) InvoiceAmountWithTax 
    from tblsoinvoiceheader
    group by TransactionDate
) b
```